# How to parse this XML in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I am quite new to XML parsing and I have my method of parsing XML. Only that method is for simple XML layouts with just 1 child node.

I now have to parse an XML file with childs that have childs that have childs (got it :)?)

This is the parse-method I have now:

```
protected Map<String, Maatschappij> getAutopechTel() {
    Map<String, Maatschappij> telVoorAutopech = new HashMap<String, Maatschappij>();

    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(getAssets().open("autopech.xml"));
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("dienst");
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nl.item(i);
            Maatschappij maat = new Maatschappij();

            maat.setNaam(Xml.innerHtml(Xml.getChildByTagName(node, "naam")));
            maat.setTel(Xml.innerHtml(Xml.getChildByTagName(node, "tel")));

            telVoorAutopech.put(maat.getTel(), maat);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return telVoorAutopech;
}
```

How must I adjust this in order to parse this type of XML file:

```
   <Message>  

    <Service>Serviceeee</Service>

      <Owner>Bla</Owner>

      <LocationFeedTo>Too</LocationFeedTo>

      <Location>http://maps.google.com/?q=52.390001,4.890145</Location>

      <Child1>

        <Child1_1>

          <Child1_1_1>ANWB</Child1_1_1>

        </Child1_1>
      </Child1>
<Message>
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: question is not about how to parse -- parsing is already done and result is DOM tree -- but rather as to how to use parsed results into something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`SAXParser`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html) to parse XML in Android :

[Here is a detailed tutorial with example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser) and [also another one here by IBM developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/).

> DOM Parser is slow and consume a lot
>   memory if it load a XML document 
>   which contains a lot of data. Please
>   consider SAX parser as solution for
>   it,  SAX is faster than DOM and use
>   less memory.

Try this one out but I haven't tested this code yet. It recursively traverses all the nodes and adds which are `ELEMENT_NODE` to the `Vector<Node>`.

```
public void traverseNodes(Node node, Vector<Node> nodeList)
{
    if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
    {
        nodeList.add(node);
        if(node.getChildNodes().getLength() >= 1)
        {
            NodeList childNodeList = node.getChildNodes();
            for(int nodeIndex = 1;nodeIndex < childNodeList.getLength(); nodeIndex++)
            {
                traverseNodes(childNodeList.item(nodeIndex),nodeList);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I've seen both links (yes i did Google before i post) but I don't want to learn/implement a diffrent XML method. I have the DOM-parser as I've shown above and I just want to adjust it to my new XML file. But tnx anyway ;)

Comment: You can parse it with DOMParser but into what? Do you have a container object to store the data and use them through?

Comment: Yes, as you can see in my code I store them into a HashMap with my own defined Object (Maatschappij).

Comment: I implemented the SAX parser en it is MUCH faster thant the DOMParser :D thank you!