# Save xml files in Android

Tags: android, xml, parsing

My problem is that I want to download xml files from Internet and save in my phone, but I don't know how develop it in Android.

Thanks

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Ok stay calm and in the meanwhile take a coffee while here we work for you.

Comment: Atleast do some research and tryout something and then if you face any proble, you can share it here. First try yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5472726/712960), its maybe helps you to save the file.

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4440608/712960) for parsing the XML.